# VBA Beginner Loop Issue

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, while-loop

My code keeps giving me only results for Sheet1.Cells(3, 1). It outputs to the correct cells using sequential i's but always from the same input in (3,1). How can I get it to loop through the inputs of the first column (3,1), (4,1) (5,1) etc.?

```
Sub CorrectName()

  Dim IndexAnswers() As String
  Dim FirstLastName As String
  Dim FirstLastNameSplit() As String

  i = 3
  While Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) <> ""

    IndexAnswers() = Split(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), ";")
    For k = 0 To UBound(IndexAnswers)
     If IndexAnswers(k) = "" Then IndexAnswers(k) = ","
     If k > 107 And k < 132 Then
      FirstLastName = FirstLastName & IndexAnswers(k)
     End If
    Next

    FirstLastNameSplit() = Split(FirstLastName, ",")
     Sheet1.Cells(i, 4) = FirstLastNameSplit(0)
     Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = FirstLastNameSplit(1) & FirstLastNameSplit(2)
  i = i + 1
  Wend


End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is you never reset the `FirstLastName` string to nothing.  Add this line immediately after your `While` line: `FirstLastName = vbNullString`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've been struggling with this for weeks! Problem solved >.<